# spark sc.textString? is there a way to read from string?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there a way to read from scala/java in memory string in spark? I don't like the fact that for simple trials I need to read a text file from disk.

Was looking for something like

```
// "invented" textString anything like this (textString) in spark?
sc.textString("hi this is my string, lets word count it")
```

While I can write a file and then read it I don't see why there is no option to play with in memory strings, isn't there such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `parallelize` function:

```
val stringRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq("hi this is my string, lets word count it"))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as `textString` in Spark, but considering what I understand from your question this is what you can do:

- read a string from what ever what source you want in Java or Scala
- parallelize the string after transforming it to a Seq to create an RDD, like the following:

  ```
  val str = "this is a string"
  val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(str))
  ```